# Ingress cannot route the apis

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

My ingress cannot route to  endpoint.

I provided everything. Nginx-controller works properly. I added the hostname bago.com as loadbalancerip. But it doesn't work.

Here is my ingres's yaml file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bago.com
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /web1/
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: web1-clusterip
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /web2/
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: web2-clusterip
                port:
                  number: 8082
```

svc and ingress running

```
bahaddin@bahaddin-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~/projects/personal/exposer/k8s-ingress$ k get svc
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.12.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    154m
web1-clusterip   ClusterIP   10.12.6.102   <none>        8081/TCP   145m
web2-clusertip   ClusterIP   10.12.9.22    <none>        8082/TCP   149m

bahaddin@bahaddin-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~/projects/personal/exposer/k8s-ingress$ k get ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS      ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
minimal-ingress   <none>   bago.com   34.102.241.199   80      121m
bahaddin@bahaddin-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~/projects/personal/exposer/k8s-ingress$
```

Here is my API java code.

```
@RequestMapping("/web1")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String foo() {
        return "hello from web1 ms";
    }

}
```

server.port=8081 on container level

my service

```
Web1-service.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web1-clusterip
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8081
  selector:
    app: web1-dp
  type: ClusterIP
```

But when I type in the browser

```
http://bago.com/web1/hello 
http://bago.com/web1/hello
```

I got a 404 not found error
**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your ingress manifest. You have two items in the list, while you want to have one. Additionally, you are missing the ingress class.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    # these are indivudal list items
    - host: bago.com
    - http: ...
```

You have to change the manifest so that you have a single item. You should also add the ingress class.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  # this should be the ingress class, i.e. nginx
  ingressClassName: my-ingress-class
  rules:
    # this list has only 1 items, which is an object. 
    # note the dash (-) 
    - host: bago.com
      http: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that for the ingress, you have class as `<none>` if your nginx-controller is making use of a class then you have to define that as `ingressClassName` under the `spec` section while creating ingress (rules).

you can identify the `classname` by describing the ingress-controller.
`kubectl describe deployments.apps <your-ingress-controller-deployment> -n=<namespace>` and look for `--ingress-class` parameter by default the classname should be `nginx`.

This class name is useful if more than one ingress-controller are present on the cluster, by defining the class we can tell which ingress-controller is responsible for which specific ingress rules.